# Round a floating point number by a given precision

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I need to get `qty` number by a specified `precision` like below:

```
qty = 0.1284
precision = 0.01
output = 0.12
```

It seems easy, buy I could not get it done because I have a `precision` above variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: tompal18 Are you sure you want 0.1284 --> 0.12 and not 0.13? Rounding is more often thought of as rounding to nearest than truncation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in that case - take in count my edit... I actually added the `Round` part so you might want to look at the original (and maybe edit my edit ^_^)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Hmm, either way, what OP  is asking for is problematic is asking for truncation drive by not exact power-of-10 values like `0.01` realized in as a binary floating point.  Need more  input from OP.

Comment: Will the precision always be a power of 10, or are other values possible? And do you want to round or truncate? The example you gives suggests truncating, but the solution you posted uses rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating math is not precise - see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

You can use [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to round - you seem to want to truncate though - you can do this mathematically:

```
qty = 0.1284
precision = 0.01 

truncated = ((qty * (1/precision)) // 1 ) * precision

print(truncated)
```

Output:

```
0.12
```

This multiplies your number with the correct factor, integer divides by 1 to get rid of remaining partial digits and multiplies by precision again to get back to your float value.

Comment: Note that rounding the number in-memory may *still* lead to display imprecisions, as most floating point numbers wil remain approximations of the decimal expectation.

Comment: It works, but when I have qty  like 181.1231231221, it prints 181.10000000000002.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like below.

```
def get_qty(qty, step_size):

    prec = 0
    if(step_size >= 1):
        return int(qty)
    while(step_size < 1):
        step_size *= 10
        prec += 1
    qty = "{:0.0{}f}".format(qty, prec)
    return float(qty)
get_qty(181.1231231221, 0.01)
get_qty(181.1231231221, 1.0)
```

Comment: Doesn't this round rather than truncating? In your original post, you say you want `get_qty(0.1284, 0.01)` to return `0.12`, but this code will return `0.13`.